# Tomcat uses project directory for relative paths

Tags: tomcat, path, jvm

I have a GWT web application that creates a cache on disk under the relative directory "cache". In my JUnit tests in eclipse it works but when I deploy it in Tomcat, the program *still* tries to create the file in `/home/username/projects/myproject/cache` (real path renamed) instead of `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myproject/cache` and because it doesn't have file write access there, it crashes. The code that creates the cache is an external library so it cannot even be hardcoded.

Could it be a symbolic link? Or can Tomcat and Eclipse share a JVM?
This error is driving me crazy.

**The error message**

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Fehler beim Erzeugen der Datei "/home/username/projects/myproject/cache"
Error while creating file "/home/username/projects/myproject/cache" [90062-143]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileSystemDisk.createDirs(FileSystemDisk.java:368)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.lockFile(FileLock.java:328)
    at org.h2.store.FileLock.lock(FileLock.java:134)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:525)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:208)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:203)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:53)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:147)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:126)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:109)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:289)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.createSession(SessionRemote.java:265)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:110)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:94)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
```

[...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
String path = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/cache")).getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Thanks that is a good way to circumvent the problem but why did it occur in the first place?

Comment: Because it is hardcoded such way:http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/store/fs/FileSystemDisk.java?r=3324#59

Comment: Ahh thank you very much! I interpreted "jdbc:h2:test in the current(!) working directory" on `http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html` as being the root directory of the jvm.

Comment: P.S.: I now get the exception `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/myapplication/cache/httplivedbpediaorgsparql_httpdbpediaorg;CACHE_SIZE=100000
`. When I test jdbc with exactly this path in Junit it works however. Do you by chance know what to do for this as well? :-)